# Files.copy() on Ubuntu throws UnixException: No such file or directory even though the file exists

Tags: java, ubuntu

I get the following error when trying to use the Files.copy() method:

http://pastebin.com/9wzEyBzH

This is the code in question:

```
public static void copyFile(File origin, File destinationDir)
{
    if(!origin.exists())
        return;

    File destination = new File(destinationDir, origin.getName());
    Logger.info("Copy File from: '" + origin.getAbsolutePath() + "' dest: '" + destination.getAbsolutePath() + "'");

    try
    {
        Files.copy(origin.toPath(), destination.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file I am trying to copy exists, I looked multiple times. The same java application works on windows with the same folder and file structure in place.

The os-specifications:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
```

This is the file that should be copied:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMzWb.png)

Comment: Does the folder you attempt to copy the file to exist?

Comment: How are you running this? The exception is coming from getcwd, which tries to determine the current working directory

Comment: The folder I copy to exists. I am running this from ssh. I created a screen session and navigated to the folder where the run.sh file is stored add. I then executed it via "sh run.sh". The line in question is "java -jar ../PPRPGServerUpdater.jar $PWD gameServer"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the destination path's permission & restart the computer.